# How much potential energy is stored in a city's elevators?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, estimation

This is probably along the lines of one of those vague Google interview questions. It also assumes naively that elevators could generate energy when going down, but yeah:

How much potential energy is stored in a city's elevators? Could there be practical benefits to harness it for grid balancing?

Edit:

back of the envelope calculation:

Gravity: $9.8 m/s^2

Empty elevator weight: ~1200KG

(assuming starting from stationary)

$s = .5at^2

sqrt(s/4.9) = t

v1 = 9.8 * sqrt(s/4.9)

kinetic energy = 600 * (9.8*sqrt(s/4.9))^2 joules/watt sec

1 storey = 4.3m = 50Kws per lift

NYC has 80k lifts

So all of them dropping 1 level would give 4million kws or 1.1Mwh

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there all have a properly calibrated counterweight: zero. However, they are probably calibrated for an empty elevator. In this case you could harvest the energy released when a load is transported down
and regain part of the energy it has cost to bring it up. The energy is not stored in the elevator system but in the loads it has transported up.

Comment: What if they didn't though? what if they were designed for this purpose?  There is a bit of buzz about gravity storage through building huge concrete towers. Just seems to me with lifts you have a lot of that physical structure already there?

Obviously lifts need to move to actually transport people though, and so can't just move when its advantageous to do so based on the energy market at the time

Comment: @matt People have to use elevators pretty often, so this would most likely be a big waste of energy to not use a counterweight. The question is whether it is more efficient to store the energy from dropping an elevator in the grid / a battery or just in the counterweight. Since your claim is that gravitational storage is so good, isn't it reasonable for you to believe that storing this energy in the counterweight is already a good, if not optimal, option?

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey the point of this is definitely not to replace the counterweight with just storing the energy in the grid instead. That would definitely not be more cost efficient, but the key is all about how flexible you can be with taking power in and out of the grid. In the case of the lift's primary usecase, thats not flexible at all (unless you force users to wait for an ideal time... not likely).

But in cases where the lifts aren't being used, you could send the lift to the top when energy prices are cheap (or even negative), and then drop it again when they are expensive.

Comment: to clarify, my idea *is* to replace the counterweight with just taking and putting energy into the grid, and that would be more inefficient when you had no control over when the lift is moving (due to passengers), but that this might be balanced out by profiting off the grid when you do have control over the lifts (when they are otherwise idle)

Comment: so how much energy is stored in all the counterweights.

Comment: @matt Trying to automate that across a city would be a nightmare, and low-hanging fruit such as energy-efficient building standards would yield much greater returns. NYC uses gigawatts of power; dropping a fraction of its elevators would be a drop in the bucket, for a few seconds. And then, since you removed the counterweight, you have use back up all that energy and more to accommodate the random unexpected elevator user.

Comment: @JEB Precisely the same amount of energy as the elevator weight times the height, for a calibrated counterweight. There's no free lunch here.

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey so how much energy is that?

Comment: @JEB You performed the back-of-the-envelope calculation in your problem statement. The calculation is the same process whether you're lifting elevators, counterweights, or anything else.